# Not getting full json response on server (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, object

I have one third party sms api:

I am sending messages throught that api, if put console.log for **response** its looks like this in my server:

```
connection:
  Socket {
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _handle: [Object],
    _parent: null,
    _readableState: [Object],
    readable: true,
    domain: null,
    _events: [Object],
    _eventsCount: 9,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: [Object],
    writable: true,
    allowHalfOpen: false,
    _bytesDispatched: 182,
    _sockname: null,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: null,
    _server: null,
    parser: [Object],
    _httpMessage: [Circular],
    read: [Function],
    _consuming: true,
    [Symbol(asyncId)]: 1805,
    [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0 },
 _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
 agent:
  Agent {
    domain: null,
    _events: [Object],
    _eventsCount: 1,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    defaultPort: 80,
    protocol: 'http:',
    options: [Object],
    requests: {},
    sockets: [Object],
    freeSockets: {},
    keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
    keepAlive: false,
    maxSockets: Infinity,
    maxFreeSockets: 256 },
 socketPath: undefined,
 timeout: undefined,
 method: 'GET',
 _ended: false,
 res: [Circular],
 aborted: undefined,
 timeoutCb: null,
 upgradeOrConnect: false,
 parser:
  HTTPParser {
    '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
    '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
    '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
    '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
    '4': null,
    _headers: [],
    _url: '',
    _consumed: false,
    socket: [Object],
    incoming: [Circular],
    outgoing: [Circular],
    maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
```

My api code(nodejs):

```
var options = {
   host: 'xxxxxx',
   port: 80,
   path: xxxxxxx,
   method: 'GET'
};
var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
   console.log('FULL RESPONSE: ', res);
   res.setEncoding('utf8');
   res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
   });
});

req.on('error', function (e) {
   console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

I want to see full response without this type of [Object] [Array] and [Circular] in my server (terminal).

If i put JSON.stringify it throws error.

Comment: please post the error you're getting

Comment: The `res` object is a stream object. The data you want will probably not be here. You will have to build the data using a string/buffer in the `res.on('data',function(chunk){...})` section. The data might come through in multiple chunks so you may also want to use `res.on('end',function(){...})` to figure out when all the data has been recieved. After that, you can process your string/buffer and use `JSON.parse` to get the data you need.

Comment: If i put JSON.parse will i get whole data?

Comment: I would recommend using a library like `node-fetch` or `request` which allow you to use callbacks/promises and abstract out streams for you. These will work well in most cases unless you are doing something very out of the box

Comment: You can only do JSON.parse after all the data is available - ie, by doing it inside `res.on('end',function(){...})` on the data collected in `res.on('data',function(chunk){...})`

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on my comment here:

The `res` object is a stream object. The data you want will probably not be here. You will have to build the data using a string/buffer in the `res.on('data',function(chunk){...})` section. The data might come through in multiple chunks so you may also want to use `res.on('end',function(){...})` to figure out when all the data has been recieved. After that, you can process your string/buffer and use `JSON.parse` to get the data you need

Sample Demonstration:

```
var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
   res.setEncoding('utf8');
   // Create a new Buffer
   var buffer = Buffer.from('');
   res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      // Each time a chunk comes through, write it to the buffer
      console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
      buffer.write(chunk);
   });
   res.on('end',function(){
      // The request is complete here, try to get the JSON string and parse it
      // TODO: handle possible parse exception
      var data = JSON.parse(buffer.toString('utf8'));
   });
});
```

I would recommend using a library like [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) or [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) which allow you to use callbacks/promises and abstract out streams for you. These will work well in most cases unless you are doing something very out of the box

Comment: BODY: <html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>
Your browser didn't send a complete request in time.
</body></html>

undefined:1

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input i

Comment: i am getting like this, i put console.log(data).

Comment: You need to make sure you call `req.end()` after your request. And the error you are seeing there is actually `JSON.parse` failing because the response is HTML and not JSON :) Can't help debug this as I don;t know the API for the service you are using.